# Binary Search - javascript - why does last item in array cause a Maximum call stack exceeded?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Wrote this to try my hands a building a Binary Search.  It is by no  means the most refactored code there is but wondering why everything works except when X is the last value in the array (i.e. x = 77)?

```
function binary_search(x, arr) {
    var len = arr.length - 1 //because index starts at 0
    var min = arr[0]
    var max = arr[0]    
    var new_arr = []

if(x < arr[0] || x > arr[len]) 
    //console.log(arr[len])
    console.log (x + " is not within array range.")
else 
    find_x(x, arr)


function find_x(x, arr) {
    var mid = Math.floor(arr.length/2) //takes care of odd numbered elements in array

    if (x === arr[mid]) 
        console.log("Found " + x)

    else if(x < arr[mid]) 
    {
        max = arr[mid]
        new_arr = arr.slice(0, mid)
        find_x(x, new_arr)
    }
    else if(x > arr[mid]) 
    {
        min = arr[mid]
        new_arr = arr.slice(mid, len)
        find_x(x, new_arr)
    }
    else
        console.log(x + " is not in array.")
}
}

var arr = [1,12,43,55,66,77]
binary_search(77, arr)
```

Comment: Insert a `console.log('x=',x,'arr=',arr);` as the first line of the `find_x` function and you shall be illuminated.

Comment: Your implementation is messy, try to avoid free variables and implement it in a way so that a `find` function only used its scoped variables. Check http://oli.me.uk/2013/06/08/searching-javascript-arrays-with-a-binary-search/ as an example of a better implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var len = arr.length
```

without `-1`, otherwise you cut off the last element

> Zero-based index at which to end extraction. slice extracts **up to but not including `end`**.

Found with a google chrome debugger - you should try it some day

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HC6yL/

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably here:

```
new_arr = arr.slice(mid, len)
```

You never set `len` within the scope of `find_x`.